# MVC Required attribute not being picked up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, attributes, html-helper

In my model I have the property with the `[Required]` attribute

```
[Required]
public string Surname { get; set; }
```

In my view I have the `ValidationMessageFor()` html helper

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

However it does not say that the field is required when I go to submit.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts (`jquery`, `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add "Jquery.Validate" to validate input datas.
But if you do not have a custome error message,required attribute of input tag is simplier.

Answer (score 1):

You should add error message to require in model like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Name")]
public string Surname { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank, this along with the Jquery Validate has fixed the issue! :)